# Android Java: Error in setting parameter sent from one activity to another java class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an Activity 'LoginPage' which contains pwd and email.

Once logged in, i am sending the 'email' value as a parameter at some random point to a class 'EmailDetails' in the following manner:-

```
obj.setEmail(email); //where obj is object of EmailDetails
```

'EmailDetails' contains the following code:-

```
public class EmailDetails
{
    public String Usermail;

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
       Usermail = email; //Username='null' & email='XYZ@yahoo.co.in'
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
      return Usermail; //Username='null'
    }
}
```

When some other random activity 'X' wants to access 'email' value in the following manner:-

```
 email=obj1.getEmail(); //where obj1 is Object of EmailDetails
```

The 'email' value return null.

So, where am i going wrong in the code? Thanks.

Comment: you can using sharedpreference to acces some value from other class.

Comment: Can you plz provide a small example, how to pass that shared preference 'email' value to the setEmail() method? I have little knowledge in SharedPreference

Comment: have you tried putting in a default constructor explicitly?

Comment: Does it matter if i put setEmail() code in the constructor of 'EmailDetails'?

Comment: i think it should work fine

Comment: Tbh, there are 12381923 gazillion SO posts related to this topic and a bunch more with a 1 second google search. Also the code you shared relates the data you want to send, not the way you are trying to send, so it's little to no use for us. As people have already answered and commented, try using SharedPreferences or just use Intents to pass data between activities :)

Comment: I tried your solution, the Username string is still null..

Comment: @Mese My question is all about how i am trying to retrieve data from a Java class to an Activity..Thanks :)

Comment: @sam88 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123668/sending-data-from-java-class-to-main-activity-using-intents http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994904/how-to-pass-values-from-a-class-to-activity-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795831/how-to-pass-data-from-a-non-activity-class-to-an-activity-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323880/pass-data-from-class-to-activity

Answer (score 0):

You have to use intents to send data from one activity to another in android
This link might help you http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/kirtan007/passing-data-from-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android/

If this will help you accept the answer as true So,it will be helpful for others too.

Comment: I am not calling 'EmailDetails' at that moment, i am only calling its method to set email using setEmail()..so i cannot use Intent for this purpose

Comment: @sam88 so make the method in the same class and call it why calling it from other class

Comment: So you are suggesting that i should access email value from LoginPage activity?

Comment: you are getting email from user?

Comment: Yes i am, but as given in the code abv, Username string still remains null even after being initialized with 'email' parameter sent to setEmail() method

Comment: you suggested that i should make the method in the same class and call it from other classes; I have made a method in LoginPage activity, but how do i call an an activity's method in another activity?

Comment: @sam88 Visit the link
http://www.android-examples.com/create-and-call-function-in-android-activity-from-another-programming-file/

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the data you get from user somewhere?
I mean does this EmailDetails class persists somewhere outside of the login activity?
try using shared preferences as most simple data persisting storage.
Here's one of most popular answers on this matter on SO [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Hope this helps!

Comment: The link you have shared, uses Intent to pass parameter from one activity to another..The issue is not the value being passed; the email value is getting correctly received in the setEmail() method's argument, however, the Username string is still null after being initialized with the passed arguments value. Thats where the problem is!

Answer (score 0):

The value is `null` because you used `this` operator, it should be

```
public void setEmail(String email)
    {
       this.Usermail = email; //Username='null' & email='XYZ@yahoo.co.in'
    }
```